# Use Hashtable with switch case in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I would need to make some decisions in PowerShell based on values in a hashtable.

Basically I need to assign users' UPN in Active Directory according to an attribute, the company one, and thought to create a hashtable containing keys and values like this

```
Key         Value
Company1    @Company1.com
Company2    @Company2.com
```

The issue I am facing is I don't know how to tell PowerShell to use a value rather than another based on the company attribute, basically I don't know how to cycle/check the company attribute against the key in the hashtable.

I've tried to use switches like

```
$a -match $hashTable
```

or

```
$a -contains $hashtable
```

with little success.

I think a hashtable is what I need here, but I am of course open to any suggestion like using external files for the match as the number of the companies I need to match is rather high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43410061/1630171) already presented a proper solution I'd like to add some more explanation.

[Hashtables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) and [`switch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) statements are essentially two different solutions to the same problem: transform an input value to a corresponding output.

```
A → "foo"
B → "bar"
C → "baz"
...
```

Hashtables are the simpler (and faster) approach, where you look up the result to the input value in a pre-defined table. Their advantage is that you can implement the associations in one place (e.g. a declaration section of your code where you define all your (static) data) and use them in a very simple manner anywhere else in your code:

```
$domains = @{
  'Company1' = '@Company1.com'
  'Company2' = '@Company2.com'
}

$name    = 'foo'
$company = 'Company1'

$addr = $name + $domains[$company]
```

`switch` statements are more complicated in their handling, but also a lot more versatile. For instance, they allow different kinds of comparisons (wildcard, regular expression) in addition to simple lookups. They also allow providing default values/actions if a value is not listed. With hashtables you need to handle those cases with an additional `if`/`else` statement like Mathias showed, unless you're fine with the empty value that hashtables return when the lookup doesn't find a match.

```
$name    = 'foo'
$company = 'Company1'

$domain = switch ($company) {
  'Company1' { '@Company1.com' }
  'Company2' { '@Company2.com' }
  default    { throw 'Unknown company' }
}

$addr = $name + $domain
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I am a noobie in the field and trying to learn as much as I can "doing" it but explanations like this are invaluable! Really appreciate the time you spent writing this.

Answer (score 3):

`-match` and `-contains` are not "switches" but *operators*.

The `-match` operator takes a string as its left hand side argument and compares it to a regular expression pattern, which your `$hashtable` is a poor substitute for.

The `-contains` operator takes a collection (an array or list) as its left hand side argument and compares it to a scalar value on the right, to see if the collection, well *contains* the scalar value. Also not immediately applicable to your hashtable.

---

You can use the `ContainsKey()` method to test whether a given key exists, then use an indexer (`$table[$key]`) to extract the value:

```
$UPNSuffix = if($HashTable.ContainsKey($User.Company)){
    # Company name exists in hashtable extract UPN suffix
    $HashTable[$User.Company]
}
else {
    # Not found, return default UPN suffix
    "@default.company1.com"
}
```

Alternatively use the `-contains` operator on the `Keys` of the hashtable in place of `ContainsKey()`:

```
$UPNSuffix = if($HashTable.Keys -contains $User.Company){
    # Company name exists in hashtable extract UPN suffix
    $HashTable[$User.Company]
}
else {
    # Not found, return default UPN suffix
    "@default.company1.com"
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Mathias for the detailed explanation which also clarified some doubts. As soon as I get home, travelling back from US to EU, I will try this but guess I've found a solution to my problem :-)